# Check with no void stamp

Tags: united-states, check

I have a check that has been used at Wal-Mart, but there's no void stamp.  Do I have to worry about my kids trying to cash it again and going though? There's no notification on it that it is void.  It looks like an unused check.

Comment: Is there anything printed on the back of the check? Normally there is when they accept a check at the register.

Comment: Why do you worry that your children would try to cash it again?

Comment: Is there a reason you are keeping it? An otherwise unmarked check isn't really proof that it was cashed.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the check has been used/cashed for the face value, you can write in large letters "VOID" almost anywhere on the check. No cashier will accept a check thus marked, at risk of problems related to this type of marking.

Comment: For such checks, I write "CASHED" or "DEPOSITED", and save "VOID" for mistakes and such.

Comment: I wrote the check for them to get stuff at Wal-Mart Mart. Ant they gave it back to me but there is no void mark any were on it. So I checked with the bank they send it was cashed. I just wonder ing if I should copy it for records and then we start it. I'm just worry some one or them might try to use it again. And a gain there is no void mark any where there is no visual indications that it has been cashed

Comment: I just marked void. So we're good on this. I Was just worried about nothing ig. I've never ran in the this kinda thing